# Regexp, that deletes all html tag's atrributes, but <a>

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

```
$body = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $body);
```

Hello there. I fund preg_replace, that finds all html tags, and removes their attributes. I need to exclude `<a>` tag from that regexp, so f.e.:

```
<sth a="awdawd"/><a href="http://awdwsrrdg.com"/>
```

should be changed to:

```
<sth/><a href="http://awdwsrrdg.com />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use regular expressions to parse or modify HTML/XML. This will just work for a few edge cases but not in a real world application**

Use a DOM Parser instead:

```
$html = '<sth a="awdawd"/><a href="http://awdwsrrdg.com"/>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($selector->query('//@*[not(parent::a)]') as $attr) {
    $attr->parentNode->removeAttribute($attr->nodeName);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: In your query `name()` refers to the attribute name, not to the tag name. To target the tag of an attribute (so the parent) you can use: `//@*[not(parent::a)]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte While `a` is a common tag in HTML, the `OP` indeed meant an attribute named `a`. (Check the question)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, looks like I got the question wrong... Yeah in that case `not(parent::a)` can be used. Thanks your hint!

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that you **should not use regex to parse xhtml** (use an html parser instead) since engine can mess up things when parsing strange characters, unless you really know what characters set you'll face.

On the other hand, if you want to use regex, you can leverage the discard technique with this regex:

```
<a\b.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(\w+).*?>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK2tO5/1)**

**Php** code

```
$re = '/<a\b.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(\w+).*?>/'; 
$str = "<sth a=\"awdawd\"/><a href=\"http://awdwsrrdg.com\"/>"; 
$subst = "<$1 />"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

If you want to use your regex, you can add the discard pattern at the beginning, like this:

```
<a\b.*?\/>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>
           ^------^-----Discard pattern flags
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
/<([b-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i
```

Edit the first group rule `[a-z]` to `[b-z]`. Now every tag, which is start `<a` will be ignored.

```
$body = preg_replace("/<([b-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $body);
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/iK0iB3/2)

> $pattern = `/<([b-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i`
>
> $replacement = `<$1$2>`
>
> $text = `<sth a="awdawd"/><a href="http://awdwsrrdg.com"/>`
>
> **OUTPUT:** `<sth /><a href="http://awdwsrrdg.com"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your alert, regex and my answer has been updated, now it looks, that it works correctly

Comment: yea, i thought of that but it ignores 'attr' attibute for example and bunch of other ones.